# repcached "Timed out waiting for operation" error with spymemcached client

Tags: java, caching, memcached, spymemcached

I setup up repcache (memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2.1). 
I tested both replicated servers via telnet(add a value and retrieved it from other node). It worked.

But, when I try to cache it in my java application throuch *spymemcach* cleint, it throws exceptions.

```
2014-08-16 14:51:05.938 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/192.168.0.1:22122, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-08-16 14:51:05.944 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@52cc8049
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for operation
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:59)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.getStatus(OperationFuture.java:101)
    at com.test.RepCacheTest.cacheObject(RepCacheTest.java:118)
    at com.test.RepCacheTest$1.run(RepCacheTest.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: /192.168.0.1:22122
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:73)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:56)
    ... 4 more
```

I use spymemcached-2.10.3.jar` client. (and tried to test with 2.7 jar. butsame exception throws)

One repcache runs on my host OS (ip: 192.168.0.1 and  repcache port 22122. And other runs in my virtual box Guest OS (192.168.0.1). How ever, I could test repcache replication with telnet and they worked well in telnet. My caching values are only 3  or 4 character size stings.  But I could cache into direct `memcached`, and it worked.

Any one let me know where my problem is?